# Starting IntelliJ for inspections in Teamcity are very slow. Is there a way to speed it up?

Tags: intellij-idea, teamcity

we are using Teamcity (9.1.7) for our maven projects and are considering to switch from checkstyle/pmd/findbugs to IntelliJ inspections as we are using IntelliJ anyways.

The problem is that the build time increases by more than 4 minutes, most of the time waiting for IntelliJ to start (if I read the build log correctly). The inspection itself is fast enough, but the starting issue really blocks us from using it.

Is there a way to speed up the start or to have IntelliJ running all the time on the agents?

Thanks!

Update: I disabled a whole bunch of plugins and the start time decreased to about 1:30. Still not good (so suggestions are still welcome) but at least usable.